# Robocopy - logs about which files have been moved

Tags: logging, robocopy

I am trying to archive old files which haven’t been modified for more than 30 days from the *SourceFolder* to the *ArchiveFolder* using the following ROBOCOPY command:

```
robocopy C:\SourceFolder C:\ArchiveFolder /mov /MINAGE:30 /copyall /s
```

It works well but I’d like to place a log file in every subfolder of  *C:\SourceFolder* to have an overview which files have been archived (which files are now missing in *C:\SourceFolder*).

Example:

**Input**

```
C:\SourceFolder\Documents\newFile1.doc
C:\SourceFolder\Documents\oldFile1.doc
C:\SourceFolder\Documents\oldFile2.doc
C:\SourceFolder\Projects\newFile1.pdf
C:\SourceFolder\Projects\oldFile1.xlsx

C:\ArchiveFolder (empty folder)
```

**Output**

```
C:\SourceFolder\Documents\newFile1.doc
C:\SourceFolder\Documents\archived_files.log
C:\SourceFolder\Projects\newFile1.pdf
C:\SourceFolder\Projects \archived_files.log

C:\ArchiveFolder\Documents\oldfile1.doc
C:\ArchiveFolder\Documents\oldfile2.doc
C:\ArchiveFolder\Projects\oldfile1.xlsx
```

where `C:\SourceFolder\Documents\archived_files.log` should contain these two rows

*oldFile1.doc*
*oldFile2.doc*

and `C:\SourceFolder\Projects\archived_files.log` should contain this one row

*oldFile1.xlsx*

Could anyone advise me how to create such logs?

Thank you